# Three.js, the lookAt function issue

Tags: three.js, webgl

I created a cone with cylinder geometry. Then when I want to rotate the cone to point to the positive direction of X axis with lookAt function, it just doesn't work. Is there anything wrong with my code? Or this is a bug of Three.js?

You can also see my code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ysmood/CRdxP/

```
class Stage
    constructor: ->
        @init_scene()
        @make_meshes()

    init_scene: ->
        @scene = new THREE.Scene

        # Renderer
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        @renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: document.querySelector('.scene')
        })
        @renderer.setSize(width, height)

        # Camera
        @camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            45,                 # fov
            width / height,     # aspect
            1,                  # near
            1000                # far
        )
        @camera.position.z = 200;
        @scene.add(@camera)

    make_meshes: ->
        size = 20
        @mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.CylinderGeometry(
                0, size, size
            ),
            new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
        )
        @scene.add(@mesh)

        # I want the mesh's tip point to right, but it doesn't work.
        @mesh.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0))

    draw: =>
        @renderer.render(@scene, @camera)

stage = new Stage
stage.draw()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All meshes by default have a `lookAt` vector set to `(0,0,1)`, and `up` vector set to `(0,1,0)`.
By setting `lookAt` vector to `(1,0,0)` you practically rotated your mesh by 90 degrees around y axis.

Look at this demo: http://threejs.org/examples/misc_lookat.html

You will find

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationFromEuler( new THREE.Vector3( Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, 0 ) ) );
```

That command modifies geometry in that way that pointy side of the cone now lays along z-axis, and later it uses `mesh.lookAt(someVector)` to reorient mesh to look at some desired point in space.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps! By the way, I think the `lookAt` vector's default value should be `(0, 0, -1)`, or the camera's lookAt vector is by default changed to `(0, 0, -1)`?

Comment: I believe that camera has default of `(0,0,-1)`. If this answer solved problem, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark left of answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to only change the `lookAt` vector? Your solution changed the initial position of the geometry, that's what I don't want. I know I could use the `lookAt` to rotate it back to `(0, 1, 0)`, but it seems a little dirty.

Comment: Besides, just the `geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(Math.PI / 2))` will play the trick. Why you also rotate the y-axis?

Comment: Maybe using the `up` instead of `lookAt` vector? So geometry itself won't be changed, but pointy side is actually in the `up` direction. I copy/pasted the code from demo just to show the principle of transforming geometry and how it could be done.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with the camera.up vector myself, so I wrote my own lookAt function that doesn't use the up vector. It simply points the camera at the target position keeping its current roll.

```
CameraUtils.lookAt = function(camera, targetPosition) {
    var targetPos = camera.worldToLocal(targetPosition.clone());
    var rotationAxis = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1),
        targetPos
    ).normalize();
    var angle = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1).angleTo(
        targetPos.normalize().clone());

    camera.rotateOnAxis(rotationAxis, angle);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
CameraUtils.lookAt(camera, myObject.position);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks dude. This is also useful for objects, not just camera.

Comment: So this similar to wrapping the camera in a parent Object3D which has rotation `0,0,0`, then calling the regular lookAt on the parent object (preserves camera's "roll" assuming the camera is still looking down Z)?